# Prolog - number to list of digits

Tags: prolog

I have a trouble with conversion a number to list of digits. What's wrong? Everything works well until it returns from recursion.

```
number_to_digits(0, [_ | _]).
number_to_digits(Number, List) :-
    Number > 0,
    NewNumber is div(Number, 10),
    Digit is mod(Number, 10),
    append([Digit], List, NewList),
    number_to_digits(NewNumber, NewList).
```

Comment: You append it to `NewList`, which you pass recursively. But it is the other way around. `List` is the *result*, whereas `NewList` will be the (temporary) result for `NewNumber`.

Comment: I've tried to swap NewList and List but I doesn't work anyway.

Comment: `number_to_digits(0,[a,b,c])` succeeds

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important skills for programming in Prolog is giving really clear names to variables and predicates. Here is your second clause with variable names changed a bit:

```
number_to_digits(Number, Digits) :-
    Number > 0,
    RemainingNumber is div(Number, 10),
    LastDigit is mod(Number, 10),
    append([LastDigit], Digits, RemainingDigits),
    number_to_digits(RemainingNumber, RemainingDigits).
```

For example, if `Number` is `123`, then its `LastDigit` is `3`, and the `RemainingNumber` after splitting off the `LastDigit` is `12`.

Assuming that `number_to_digits` works correctly, `RemainingDigits` should then be `[1, 2]`. So your `append` call is:

```
append([3], Digits, [1, 2])
```

but this cannot have any solutions. Rather, the digits of `123` can be obtained by calling:

```
append([1, 2], [3], Digits)
```

So your code should read:

```
append(RemainingDigits, [LastDigit], Digits)
```

If you correct your first clause as well (are the digits of `0` really any non-empty list?), then this allows you to make progress:

```
?- number_to_digits(123, Digits).
Digits = [1, 2, 3] ;
% nontermination
```

This finds the correct solution, but it goes into an infinite search when you ask it for more answers. This is because there is not enough information about `RemainingDigits` at the time of the `append` call, so Prolog tries longer and longer lists. The problem is fixed if you swap the last two goals, i.e., put the `append` call after the recursive `number_to_digits` call:

```
?- number_to_digits(123, Digits).
Digits = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

When asking for more answers, Prolog now correctly tells us that there are no more.